# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable in a Pandas Dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am trying to do is create a new column in a dataframe called 'nouns' and keep all the nouns from a column that I have removed stopwords from.

The problem is that in the drug data set I am using, there must be float objects in the drug review column somewhere because it won't let me iterate over it.  I read that I could use range() but I am not sure how that would translate into my loop as I am not sure on the range and also I read that .dropna could work but as far as I am aware there are no null values in any of the rows.

My code:

```
df['nouns'] = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['noStopwordsReview']), axis=1) 
noun=[]
for  index, row in df.iterrows():
    noun.append([word for word,pos in pos_tag(row[0]) if pos == 'NN'])
df['nouns'] = noun
```

The traceback in its entirety:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/Users/matthewrook/OneDrive - AUT University/Year 3/Data Mining/assignment1.py", line 76, in <module>
    noun.append([word for word,pos in pos_tag(row[0]) if pos == 'NN'])

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 161, in pos_tag
    return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger, lang)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 118, in _pos_tag
    tagged_tokens = tagger.tag(tokens)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py", line 181, in tag
    context = self.START + [self.normalize(w) for w in tokens] + self.END

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: can you include the content of `df`

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  In particular, print the data values at the point of error.  For instance, what is `pos_tag(row[0])` at that point?

Comment: @reza the content of df in the nouns column is over 3000 rows but here is ta small part of the content

['  '.', 'I', 'took', '2', 'pills','every', '8-12', 'hours', 'took', '1', 'pill', 'needed', '3-4', 'days', 'cramps', 'over','take', 'every', '8', 'hours', 'dot', 'medication', 'stops', 'working', , '..', 'cramps', 'moderate', ',', 'taking', 'every', '12', 'hours', 'okay', '.']
the tokenized sample of data as shown above is at the point of error.  As soon as it starts iterating through the rows, it flags the error

Comment: Hi @MatthewRook, I think one of the inverted commas is missing/an extra inverted comma is there at the very beginning in your row. This is what you have provided:  [' '.',]. Please check that!